# Changing data in React Native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a react native project, that gives the user an update on the COVID-19 situation, using the "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api" the app by default returns a global count, and then the user can select a country and get the specific info for that, I watched a youtube tutorial yet as a beginner I have a problem, I am doing buttons for the country names instead of select and option,
but when I choose a certain country the count does not change and I get no errors.
here is the code:`

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import * as React from 'react';
// import { OptionsButton } from 'react-native-options-button';
import { Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Alert, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getCountryData = this.getCountryData.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    confirmed: 0,
    recovered: 0,
    deaths: 0,
    countries: [],
  }
  //We set a state with initial values that we can change later on after we get the 
  //proper info using the SetState method.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  //Automatically calls this function:
  async getData() {
    const resAPI = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api")
    const resCountries = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
    const countries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resCountries.data.countries.length; i++) {
      countries.push(resCountries.data.countries[i].name);
    }


    this.setState({
      confirmed: resAPI.data.confirmed.value,
      recovered: resAPI.data.recovered.value,
      deaths: resAPI.data.deaths.value,
      countries
      //changes the original state of countries which i an empty array to the new state 
      //which has the key for each country.
    })
  }
  async getCountryData(event) {
    const res = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/NL/" + event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      confirmed: res.data.confirmed.value,
      recovered: res.data.recovered.value,
      deaths: res.data.deaths.value
    })
  }
  rendercountryoptions() {
    return this.state.countries.map((name, i) => {
      return <Button title={name} onPress={this.getCountryData} value={name} key={name} />
    });
  }
  //Async function because it is waiting (await) for a promise to be applied which is 
  // for axios to get the info in the link, then get the specific data needed.
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView >
        <Text>Corona Update</Text>
        <Text>Confirmed cases </Text>
        <Text>{this.state.confirmed}</Text>
        <Text>Recovered cases</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.recovered}</Text>
        <Text>Death cases</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.deaths}</Text>
        {this.rendercountryoptions()}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
export default HomeScreen
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works , tested :

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import * as React from 'react';
// import { OptionsButton } from 'react-native-options-button';
import { Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Alert, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getCountryData = this.getCountryData.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    confirmed: 0,
    recovered: 0,
    deaths: 0,
    countries: [],
  }
  //We set a state with initial values that we can change later on after we get the
  //proper info using the SetState method.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  //Automatically calls this function:
  async getData() {
    const resAPI = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api")
    const resCountries = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
    const countries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resCountries.data.countries.length; i++) {
      countries.push(resCountries.data.countries[i].name);
    }


    this.setState({
      confirmed: resAPI.data.confirmed.value,
      recovered: resAPI.data.recovered.value,
      deaths: resAPI.data.deaths.value,
      countries
      //changes the original state of countries which i an empty array to the new state
      //which has the key for each country.
    })
  }
  async getCountryData(name) {
    const res = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/" + name);
    this.setState({
      confirmed: res.data.confirmed.value,
      recovered: res.data.recovered.value,
      deaths: res.data.deaths.value
    })
  }
  rendercountryoptions() {
    return this.state.countries.map((name, i) => {
      return <Button title={name} onPress={() => this.getCountryData(name)} value={name} key={name} />
    });
  }
  //Async function because it is waiting (await) for a promise to be applied which is
  // for axios to get the info in the link, then get the specific data needed.
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView >
        <Text>Corona Update</Text>
        <Text>Confirmed cases </Text>
        <Text>{this.state.confirmed}</Text>
        <Text>Recovered cases</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.recovered}</Text>
        <Text>Death cases</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.deaths}</Text>
        {this.rendercountryoptions()}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
export default HomeScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onPress={() => this.getCountryData({name})}
```

And

```
async getCountryData({name})
```

Also, bind all of the other methods in the constructor.
Also, getData and getCountryData should be in the same method instead of repeat your code.

Comment: where should I put async getCountryData({name})?

Comment: just update it.. so instead of sending the full event, just send the value you need. BTW, try to debug and log the param you receive in this method, see ifs not null or something.

Comment: I changed it back to how it was, and I bind the other methods and changed the onPress. to onPress={() => this.getCountryData({name})}  When I press one of the buttons I get a warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection?